React-Admin Authentication: Path /auth-callback not found when deployed to Azure Static Web App
I configured React-Admin Authentication using Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure AD) per the following tutorial,
React-Admin Authentication Using Active Directory
The authentication works when running the application locally using Vite.
The authentication does not work when building and deploying the application to an Azure Static Web App, returning a 404 Not Found error for the https://.azurestaticapps.net/auth-callback path.
I had to include the VITE_ environment variables in the Azure Static Web App workflow file to be included in the build, e.g.
env:
  VITE_APP_BASE_URL: https://<subdomain>.azurestaticapps.net:443

I tried both including and removing port 443.

nextjs project isn't to be hosted on static server, use nextjs(if exists) or nodejs
